# Finding performance bottlenecks on Red Hat server hosting KVMs with QEMU?

Tags: rhel, performance, kvm, qemu

As a side task I administer a RHEL 7 server used as an internal KVM host. Now it runs eight VMs which, but for one, are idle most of their time, or at least not doing anything at all resource intensive. However, new VMs will be periodically added, some of which will not be so idle.

I know what I'm doing as far as setting up the VMs, configuring them, networking them, all the stuff it takes to make them run at least well enough to do their job.

How do I spot the host itself slowing down/reaching performance bottlenecks under new loads? There is ample RAM and CPU cores for the load now, but with an indeterminate number of future VMs spun up, it's only a matter of time before it starts to buckle under new loads. I don't really know what to watch for, to catch performance problems before they become *real* problems, besides just keeping an eye on RAM usage and the [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/)/KVM processes in [top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html).

This server is an old [Dell T620](https://i.dell.com/sites/content/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/dell-poweredge-t620-technical-guide.pdf) with two Xeon E5-2660 CPUs and 96 GB RAM,, The VM  files are stored on an XFS-formatted RAID-10 array built on a set of 5400-rpm 3.5" disks (which I realize is not ideal, but I have to work with what I have).

Comment: I am a huge fan on `XYMon` which can be used for this purpose but also used to monitor any computer.

Answer (score 1):

[Virt-Manager](http://virt-manager.org) and the [QEMU Monitor Console](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/virtualization/html/book.virt/cha.qemu.monitor.html) will do all you have asked for, but if it is not suitable, look at others [listed here](http://linux-kvm.org/page/Management_Tools).